# Digitally Sign SOAP Service Reference

Tags: c#, soap, sign, service-reference

I've been bagging my head for over a week with this. I've requested help from several Microsoft friends, but still no luck.

We are developing an online conference registration portal which requires online payments.

Unfortunately our Customer does not accept any other payment method other than a local (Chilean) payment Gateway (Transbank's [WebPay Plus](https://www.transbank.cl/public/personas/todo-sobre-tus-medios-de-pago/webpay-plus/)).

*We tried to get them onboard with PayPal and several other's, but they would not accept for several reasons. So...we are stuck with WebPay Plus (WPP).*

WPP accepts a SOAP request to initiate the transaction. *But the request has to be digitally signed.*

We have created the web reference and we are able to reach the server end, but we have not figured out how to digitally sign the request.

WPP requires us to créate a certificate with OpenSSL, which we did (oneclick.crt).

***This is our code:***

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding _binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress _endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://201.238.207.131:7003/WSWebpayTransaction/cxf/WSWebpayService");
ServiceReference3.WSWebpayServiceClient ws3 = new ServiceReference3.WSWebpayServiceClient(_binding, _endpointAddress);
ws3.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());

var _certificatePath = "~/oneclick.crt".ToAbsolutePath();
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(_certificatePath);
apiTransbank.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
ws3.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

var tI = new ServiceReference3.wsInitTransactionInput();
tI.wSTransactionType = ServiceReference3.wsTransactionType.TR_NORMAL_WS;
tI.sessionId = "xmsbs_calculate";
tI.returnURL = "http://www.test.cl";
tI.finalURL = "http://www.test.cl/final";
tI.transactionDetails = new[] { 
    new ServiceReference3.wsTransactionDetail()
    {
        amount = 1,
        commerceCode = "XXXXXXXXXX",
        buyOrder = "1000"
    }
};
var _output = ws3.initTransaction(tI);
```

This request gives me the following response: **"An error was discovered processing the  header".**

I have talked to WPP Support and the only thing they are wiling to say is that the request is not digitally signed.

So now we need to digitally sign this request and I cannot find anywhere how to do this (at least in a way I can understand, with clear code examples).